# Text in link jumps down 1px on hover

Tags: html, css

When hovering cursor over the link, it's like it jumps down or adds extra pixel on the bottom. Looks like a common problem. I've tried solutions I found on this site, but none seem to work.

This is js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/srhjv284/

This is html

```
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#" class="item">Item 1 text</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Some Other Text</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Last Item</a>
</div>
```

And this is css

```
.wrap {width:200px;}
.item {
  display:block;
  margin:2px 0;
  padding:4px 8px;
  background-color:#fff;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:15px;
  color:#ba050a;
  border:1px solid #ba050a;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition:0.4s;
}
.item:hover {
  color:#fff;
    background-color:#ba050a;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me; the text stays in the same position when I hover.

Comment: Does it still look like it jumps to you, here? https://jsfiddle.net/srhjv284/1/ - and what about here? https://jsfiddle.net/srhjv284/2/

Comment: With the CSS you have here it's not supposed to change the size of something.

Answer (score 0):

This is just happening because you have the same border colour and the background colour on hover.
So when you hover, 1px border merge with background and it feels like that space increased.
Please change the border colour or background colour on hover and you will see the difference.